# Magento Database Checkbox During Checkout

Tags: php, html, magento

I am working on a Magento site http://mydolcessa.com

I have added a checkbox to the checkout page that confirms they are authorizing the company to charge their credit card and acknowledge to return and refund policy. (as seen below)

In the admin area where you see the orders I have added a line saying "Authorized to Charge: " currently if I manually enter the value into the database in the column I have setup it will read and display there correctly.

What I need help with is making the checkbox insert Yes or No into the column in the database.

**Checkbox Code on app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/Ccsave.phtml**

```
<li>

    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_checkbox"" name="payment[cc_checkbox]" title="<?php echo $this->__('By checking this box, I authorize this transaction and acknowledge the refund/exchange policy discussed in the "customer care" section of the website.') ?>" class="input-text validate-cc-checkbox validate-cc-type" value="Yes" />

      <label for="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_checkbox" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('By checking this box, I authorize this transaction and acknowledge the refund/exchange policy discussed in the "customer care" section of the website.') ?></label>


    </div>
</li>
```

**Checkbox Code on app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Cc.php**

```
/**
 * Retrieve Checkbox Status
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCcCheckbox()
{
    $checkbox = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getCcCheckbox();
    $ccCheckbox = $this->getInfo()->getCcCheckbox();
    if (isset($checkbox[$ccCheckbox])) {
        return $checkbox[$ccCheckbox];
    }
    return (empty($ccCheckbox)) ? Mage::helper('payment')->__('No') : $ccCheckbox;
}
```

**Checkbox Code on app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Ccsave.php (Shows in the Backend)**

```
class Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Ccsave extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cc
{
/**
 * Show name on card, expiration date and full cc number 
 *
 * Expiration date and full number will show up only in secure mode (only for admin, not in emails or pdfs)
 *
 * @param Varien_Object|array $transport
 */
protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
{
    if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
        return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
    }
    $info = $this->getInfo();
    $transport = new Varien_Object(array(Mage::helper('payment')->__('Name on the Card') => $info->getCcOwner(),));

    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
    if (!$this->getIsSecureMode()) {
        $transport->addData(array(
            Mage::helper('payment')->__('Expiration Date') => $this->_formatCardDate(
                $info->getCcExpYear(), $this->getCcExpMonth()
            ),
            Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number') => $info->getCcNumber(),
            Mage::helper('payment')->__('Authorized to Charge') => $info->getCcCheckbox(),
        ));
    }
    return $transport;
}
}
```

Where should I be placing the code like something like this?

```
<?php $cc_checkbox = $_GET["cc_checkbox"];

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_payment');

    if ($cc_checkbox == true) { 
        $checked="Yes";
        $query = "UPDATE INTO {$tableName} (cc_checkbox)
        VALUES ('Yes')";
    }
    else { 
        $checked="No"; 
        $query = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} (cc_checkbox)
        VALUES ('No')";
    }

    $writeConnection->query($query);

    ?>
```

PS: I know about editing base files, I do this and then copy over to my folders.

[image: Checkbox on Saved Credit Card Form]

[image: AUthorized to Charge in Order Section]

Comment: You might be better off using the Terms and Conditions option instead (Sales->Terms and Conditions). It adds whatever block of text you want to the review section, and a customer is required to check the box in order to place the order.

Comment: thought about that but unfortunately the company that the customer uses to process credit cards requires for the checkbox to be right here and be able to see that on an invoice which is the way I have it setup, just need to figure out how to insert the yes or no into the database and then I am done.